# Passar parâmetro para outra page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Dentro de pessoas, eu possuo a tabela contas a receber, onde estou chamando a page contas a receber create, e a edit. Até aí, está funcionando perfeitamente.
Porém, dentro de contas a receber, eu tenho um `select`, onde eu já queria que viesse selecionado a pessoa que eu estava. E também tem o retornar lista.

Precisava saber como posso fazer, por exemplo, passando um parâmetro, se está sendo chamado de contas a receber ou de pessoas, para, na hora de retornar, eu fazer o tratamento para saber onde voltar.

Aqui é o create:

```
 <a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Criar nova Conta</a>
```

E aqui o edit:

```
 <a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Editar</a>
```

Ele redireciona, porém preciso de tratar, igual informei.

Este é o parâmetro ID pessoa que preciso passar para a outra página:

```
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="PessoaVM.Pessoas.Id" name="id" id="id" />
```

Edit:
Conseguir passar o id para a page ContaReceber/Create desta forma:

```
  <a asp-page="/ContaReceber/Create" asp-route-id="@Request.Query["id"]" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Criar nova Conta</a>
```

Porém não estou sabendo como tratar aqui dentro:

```
  public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ContasReceberVM = new ContasReceberViewModel
        {
            ContasReceber = new ContasReceber(),
            PessoaVM = _context.Pessoas.ToList(),
            PlanosServicos = _context.PlanosServicos.ToList()
        };
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
    {
        ContasReceberVM = new ContasReceberViewModel
        {
            ContasReceber = new ContasReceber(),
            PessoaVM = _context.Pessoas.Where(m => m.Id == id).ToList(),
            PlanosServicos = _context.PlanosServicos.ToList()
        };
        return Page();
    }
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult OnGet(), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult OnGet(Int32)

Comment: para passar isso para outra página, você poderia usar uma QueryString, certo? Por que não faz isso?

Comment: Mas como posso passar direto ? No caso aqui eu chamo a página, /ContaReceber/Create e eu preciso passar o idpessoa, que é um hidden.

Comment: @marianac_costa Você não precisa usar snippet de código em código que não vai se executado. Nestes casos você pode apenas formatar o código com 4 espaços.

Comment: Não sei como fazer em asp.net-core, mas a ideia seria: `ContaReceber/Create?PessoaId=@IDPessoaAqui`

Comment: Sim, a ideia seria esta, isto que eu estou tentando, porém não estou conseguindo.

Comment: @marianac_costa poderia mostrar pra nós o que já tentou fazer?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei a pergunta. Lembrando que eu tenho o load da página create sem o parâmetro, e com o parâmetro.

Comment: Ele já está recebendo o id normal, estou passando em onget(int id), porém quando o id vem vazio, ele não carrega o select, eu preciso tratar que se ele for vazio trás todos, senão trás o id.

Comment: É mais ou menos [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485069/asp-net-core-and-asp-route-id)?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79692/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-marianac-costa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invés de duas `actions` tenha apenas uma e permita que o **ID** seja *nullable* e faça o tratamento dentro dela.

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
{
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        ContasReceberVM = new ContasReceberViewModel
        {
            ContasReceber = new ContasReceber(),
            PessoaVM = _context.Pessoas.Where(m => m.Id == id).ToList(),
            PlanosServicos = _context.PlanosServicos.ToList()
        };
    }
    else
    {
        ContasReceberVM = new ContasReceberViewModel
        {
            ContasReceber = new ContasReceber(),
            PessoaVM = _context.Pessoas.ToList(),
            PlanosServicos = _context.PlanosServicos.ToList()
        };
    }
    string urlAnterior = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    if (urlAnterior.Contains("Pagina"))
        return RedirectToAction("");
    else
        return RedirectToAction("");
}
```

E na *view* o botão pode ficar assim:

```
<a asp-controller="ContaReceber" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="PessoaVM.Pessoas.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Editar</a>
```

Comment: Cheguei nesta resposta @Barbetta .. Uma dúvida, como posso fazer pra no caso na hora de salvar, ele saber pra onde redirecionar? Posso usar o mesmo id ?

Comment: você deseja saber de qual página ele veio antes?

Comment: Isso, para que na hora que salvar, ou ele clicar em retornar, ele retorne para a página correta.

Comment: @marianac_costa atualizei a resposta, com o código ele pega qual era a página anterior

Comment: Se eu faço desta forma, ele volta para a create normal atualizada e não para a de pessoas ou de contas a receber.

Comment: você está dando postback na página? acredito que seja por isso, vou ver aqui se acho uma solução fácil para isso.